# What is the proper way to center a math condition in its own line?

Tags: positioning

I have a condition of the form `$E1$ and $E2$`, where `E1` and `E2` are long expressions. The condition is important and I've put it into its own line with the `align` environment. See the snippet below.

```
\begin{align*}
    E_1~\text{ and }~E_2.
\end{align*}
```

The problem is that there is too little space between the word `and` and the two expressions. What's the best way to handle this? I'd like to avoid adding many `~`'s; I could use `&` (i.e. `E_1 &~&\text{ and }&~& E_2`) but that puts `E1` to the far left, `and` to the center, and `E2` to the far right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single line displays should always use `\[` not `align*` so I would possibly use

```
\[
E1
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
E2
\]
```

but hard to say as you have not provided a real example.

Comment: This works like a charm.

Comment: What about `equation*` vs. `\[`?

Comment: @blazs what about it, by default latex only defines `\[` `equation*` is defined by the amsmath package to be the same as `\[`